# Check if no data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I created a page where I can show MySQL datas in a table. If a company has more than 1 partner, it prints all the partners with a counter. If a company has 1 partner, it prints it without the counter. But I want to print nothing if a company didn't have a partner. How can I do this?

### PHP

```
$rowcount = $result2 -> num_rows;

        // Create the table
        $output .= '
            <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-bordered">'; 

        if($result1 === false) {
            die(print_r(mysqli_error($conn), true));
        }

        while($row = $result1 -> fetch_assoc()) { 
            $output .= '
                <tr>  
                    <td align="center" width="50%"><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td align="center" width="50%">'.$row["name"].'</td>   
                </tr>

                <tr>  
                    <td align="center" width="50%"><b>Description</b></td>
                    <td align="center" width="50%">'.$row["desc"].'</td>   
                </tr>';
        }

        while($row = $result2 -> fetch_assoc()) {
            if($rowcount > 1) {
                $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="50%"><b>'.$counter.'. Partner</b></td>
                    <td align="center" width="50%"><b>Partner:</b> '.$row["partner"].'<br/>
                        <b>Country:</b> '.$row["country"].'<br/>
                   </td>   
                </tr>
            ';
            $counter++;
            } else if($rowcount == 1) {
                $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="50%"><b>Partner</b></td>
                        <td align="center" width="50%"><b>Partner:</b> '.$row["partner"].'<br/>
                            <b>Country:</b> '.$row["country"].'<br/>
                        </td>    
                    </tr>
                ';
            } else {
                // empty
            }
        }

        $output .= "</table></div>"; 

        echo $output;
```

Comment: Couldn't you do a null check or if the count is = to zero?

Comment: Why not use a CSS counter?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't works.

Comment: Edit your question and show the SQL statement you are using. I suspect you can edit/add a where clause to exclude the rows with no partners

Comment: @derrex What output is generated with your source code now when `$rowcount` is `0`? Since your `else` block is empty there shouldn't be a row created.

Comment: @Progman It's print the partner but it's empty.

Comment: @derrex Please edit your question to include the generate HTML code you get when you run your script. Also include the output of `var_dump($rowcount);` as well.